# How can I ensure that the parameter passed to a function is of a same type as the parameter of a previous function?

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to call a function called `createLoadBalancer(name: string)`, and then call another function called `attachInstanceToLb(lbName: string)` while ensuring at compile time that the `lbName` of the second call has been used in the first call.

My initial, naive thought, was to do the following:

```js
type LoadBalancerName = "first" | "second";
const createLoadBalancer(name: LoadBalancerName) = () => { ... }
const attachInstanceToLb(lbName: LoadBalancerName) = () => { ... }
```

but the issue with that solution is that I can still call

```js
createLoadBalancer('first');
attachInstanceToLb('second');
```

and TypeScript won't complain.

How can I ensure that the `attachInstanceToLb` function can only be called with load balancer names that have been used as a parameter when calling `createLoadBalancer()`?

Comment: `(function(name: LoadBalancerName) { createLoadBalancer(name); attachInstanceToLb(name) })('first')`? This isn't up to the type system, it's the abstractions you expose to consumers.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't track arbitrary state changes in your program.  There's no easy way for the compiler to distinguish the state of the world before and after you call `createLoadBalancer()`.  The "correct" way to do this is to represent state changes with new values; for your example it might look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO15lm). Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the answer. Your suggestion doesn't fully address the question in the sense that I would prefer a purely TS way to solve the issue; but if you say that's it's not possible then it's not possible :-) If you write up an answer I will accept it: even though it's kind of a workaround I think that it's the only way to achieve what I want

Comment: What does "purely TS" mean here?  Are you saying you won't change anything about the code?  Then no, it's not possible.  If you're willing to pass a state parameter around to hold onto state changes then you can do [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLXvvm) with assertion functions.  How should we proceed?

Comment: I like this new approach, that's exactly the kind of solution that I was looking for :-) Would you mind showing it as an answer with a few explanations (in particular, I would be interested to know if the "state" property could be typed in a more specific way than "any")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript's type system doesn't model arbitrary state changes, and it doesn't model *global* state changes at all.  Generally speaking it sees values as having types, and these types don't really change.  Well, there is some ability for the compiler to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of a value in some scope, but these don't track arbitrary changes. There's no way to tell TypeScript that

```
createLoadBalancer('first');
attachInstanceToLb('second'); // error
createLoadBalancer('second');
attachInstanceToLb('first');
```

is bad but that

```
createLoadBalancer('first');
attachInstanceToLb('first');
createLoadBalancer('second');
attachInstanceToLb('second');
```

is good, because it would involve having function calls have some sort of global side-effects and TypeScript can't track that.

---

The closest I can imagine getting to this would be to change your functions into [*assertion* functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which can narrow (and only narrow) the apparent type of one of their parameters. So that would mean you'd have to add a parameter to keep track of the state, and give that parameter a type which gets narrower after each call.  Here's one possibility:

```
interface State extends Partial<Record<LoadBalancerName, true>> {}
const state: State = {};

function createLoadBalancer<K extends LoadBalancerName>(
  state: State, name: K): asserts state is Record<K, true> {
  state[name] = true;
}

function attachInstanceToLb<T extends State>(
  state: T, name: keyof T) {
};
```

So when you call `createLoadBalancer(state, val)`, the type of `state` is narrowed to something where the property with key at `val` has a `true` value:

```
// const state: State
createLoadBalancer(state, "first");
// const state: Record<"first", true>
attachInstanceToLb(state, "first");
attachInstanceToLb(state, "second"); // error
createLoadBalancer(state, "second");
// const state: Record<"first", true> & Record<"second", true>
attachInstanceToLb(state, "second"); // okay
```

That sort of works, but it's fragile.  If you do some of the calls in one scope and the rest in another, the compiler might fail to see that they happen in the necessary order.  And if you find yourselves needing to represent *more* state, (e.g., after you `attachInstanceToLb` you can't do it a second time for the same key) you might eventually find yourself unable to represent that state change as a narrowing.

---

The "right" way to do things like this in TypeScript is to think about refactoring away from representing state changes as side-effects and toward representing state as different values.  That means: each call to `createLoadBalancer()` returns a new object which knows about the specific key, so it's not possible to even represent an incorrect call:

```
function createLoadBalancer(name: LoadBalancerName) {
  return {
    attachInstance() {        }
  }
}

const lbFirst = createLoadBalancer("first");
lbFirst.attachInstance();
const lbSecond = createLoadBalancer("second");
lbSecond.attachInstance();
```

Here `lbFirst` knows about `"first"` and there's no way to have it `attachInstance("second")`.  And the same with `lbSecond`.  You might not be able to refactor this way, but it will behave much better than arbitrary state changes or assertion functions.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9#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-jodBNsomU2kMyycxDrjVlgj2v60f1DHpLXaxtN5s1VpKFQAZEbw6WsyFtBWyraGOiHQHEM7g6qw-UbNqo2KWKyQCJBAjiBdyIgvBA4HQWgB5YkAKyST35xFE4iQitTOTymh0Hs1Zj7Ee9AyGKLGiYVyc2aYu7X3W1y6j5BEBSAmDE4dCjN+P5IL6HZ4oguxfiB1R0jU8JCnUEoFhgxLsBqBZaHKSYZEq9C7GWxg5o4qHoRaAB0YH+hBEBQVe+ZIKhnjhiEUJ3vKEBvmm2gNgOV5MSxMiUW29rUVsdEToQVRIEAA)